# Rails 5 - Assets Not Working in Production

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have my application working fine locally in my development environment, however when I push to Heroku OR do `RAILS_ENV=production rails s` some of my JavaScript assets are not working.  For example, I am using the `cocoon` gem and a datetimepicker that I found online (and placed into `vendor/assets/javascripts`).  I have run `RAILS_ENV=production rails assets:precompile` and all of the assets that are not working I see in `public/assets`.  Additionally, when I view the source on my pages and open up the application.js file, I can tell that the 3rd party JavaScript files are indeed compiled into the application.js because I have searched for some specific string literals and see them.  Yet `cocoon` is not working and in my browser console I see `TypeError: $(...).datetimepicker is not a function`.

I am stumped since these are working in my development environment and all of the assets appear to be compiled into the `application.js` file.  Any ideas on how to resolve this or even any direction on troubleshooting the issue further?

Edit:

So I stumbled upon this SO post: [Disable Asset Minification in Rails Production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9674714/disable-asset-minification-in-rails-production?rq=1), where the OP posted

> In order to debug javascript in my heroku production environment, I need to disable asset compression (or at least compression of javascript).

And one of the comments recommended commenting out this line in `production.rb`: `config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier` and add in `config.assets.debug = true`.  Well I did this and BAM everything is working.  Why is this?  How can `uglifier` be breaking my code?

Comment: If it's a library, make sure you're including it before any other code that uses it.