# How to stop certain assets from being minified

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

I've followed the answer from this thread:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/15625461/7429535

This has worked, in that it stops all css files from being minified.

Would it be possible to only do this for a single css file?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You could add a comment at the top of the CSS file and check for it:

Modified version from the other answer:

> create a module that does nothing to compress js / css here: `lib/modules/no_compression.rb`

```
class NoCompression
  def compress(string)
    if string.starts_with?("/* nocompress */")
      string
    else
      compressor = YUI::CssCompressor.new
      compressor.compress(string)
    end
  end
end
```

and add the comment `/* nocompress */` to the top of your CSS file